# RenderPlotly Plot as empty

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to display a plot created by `plotly` in an R Shiny UI in the third box where each box is rendered by `shinydashboard::box(...)`

In my case the plot created by plotly is named fig.

I am using the following steps to create the plot

```
output$barcharting  <- plotly::renderPlotly(fig)
 
output$final_chart <- shiny::renderUI({shinydashboard::box(title = "Table", status ='primary',
                                                           solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = FALSE, width = 12, shiny::uiOutput(outputId = session$ns("barcharting")))
  })
```

And my UI looks like this

```
shiny_modUI <- function(id){

  ns <- NS(id)
  
  shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::fluidRow(uiOutput(ns("ui_1"))),
    uiOutput(ns("ui_2")),
    uiOutput(ns("final_chart"))
  )

}
```

I see that the third box in the UI is empty, even after I verified running the code to generate
fig and that fig is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the full code. But perhaps you have to replace

```r
uiOutput(outputId = session$ns("barcharting"))
```

with

```r
plotlyOutput(outputId = session$ns("barcharting"))
```